# understanding Rails routes default parameter named as route name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have noticed that rails keeps passing to the route action a parameter with a value as an empty hash. for example if i define this route:

```rb
get "idk" => "home#index"
```

the action will receive `params[:idk]`:

```rb
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
        puts params.keys
    end
end
```

output:

```
controller
action
idk
```

server log:

```
Processing by HomeController#index as */*
  Parameters: {"idk"=>{}}
```

and in case of `resources`, I get a parameter in singular form:

```rb
resources :members
```

in this case I receive a `params[:member]` and not `params[:members]`, server logs:

```
Processing by MembersController#index as */*
  Parameters: {"member"=>{}}
```

I'm curios who sets this parameter and why is it empty?

Comment: Rails is convention based and uses the names of your route to define the entity you are passing to the controller (idk and member in your cases above).  The hash is empty because there are no attributes being passed. In the case of resources, you are typically passing the values for one resource at a time, which is why Rails uses the singular.

Comment: This behavior is done by and can configure with [`ActionController::ParamsWrapper`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html).